# Do I need to have a visa for doing research in Germany for 90 days even if I have EU temporary resident permit (titled student) issued by Poland?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas

Recently I got a research grant from an institute in Germany which I need to be there fore 3 months. Do I need any visa in case I have a temporary resident permit of EU (with the title of student) issued by Poland? Just need to be clarified. A secretary told me I need to apply for research D type schengen visa? Somebody could clarify to me?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are special conditions on it, the Polish permit allows you to travel to the rest of the Schengen area *as if* you had a 90/180 short-stay visa. A short-stay visa is for tourism and business visits.

The secretary informed you that research under the grant exceeds the scope allowed by business purposes. Basically, a business visa lets you **talk about work** done abroad while in Germany, it does not let you **do the work** while in Germnay.

Answer (score 1):

> A secretary told me I need to apply for research D type <strike>schengen</strike> national visa?

No, a research visa is not required if you have a Schengen/EU **residence permit** that is valid for the whole period.

The institute in Germany should inform the **Federal Office of Migration and residence** of the details (including the details of your polish residence permit).

- [§16c - Mobility of students - AufentG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0294)

---

> [BAMF - Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge - Mobility in the EU](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/MobilitaetEU/mobilitaeteu-node.html)
>
> **Entry and residence as part of EU mobility**
>
> Students, researchers and intra-corporate transferees who already hold a residence title from another EU Member State can enter and stay in Germany as part of EU mobility. For short-term mobility, a German residence title isn't needed; the host entity in the first EU Member State or the receiving higher education institution respectively the receiving research organisation in Germany only has to send a notification to the Federal Office [of Migration and residence]. The normal regulations for entry and residence apply in spite of the current situation:
>
> - As a matter of principle, mobile students may enter Germany 30 days after the Federal Office has received the complete notification if the Office has not issued a rejection within this period.
> - Mobile researchers and intra-corporate transferees may enter the country as soon as the Federal Office receives the complete notification.
>
> <strike>Please however note that entry restrictions are currently in place at the borders. Due to the measures that have been imposed concerning Corona, there may therefore be controls on entry, and people may even be turned back.</strike> If a subsequent rejection is issued, the mobile third-country nationals must terminate their residence without undue delay and leave the country.
>
> Residence as part of mobility is only possible via a valid residence title issued by another EU Member State. The competent immigration authority should be notified without undue delay if the residence title of the other State expires during residence in Germany and it is not possible to have it extended in time due to the current situation.

**Note**: since all of the Corona regulations have expired, I have struck out the passage from the original text that, I assume, hasn't yet been updated. Portions with 'the current situation' also reference the now expired Corona regulations.

Comment: This is what I got ::
The XXXX offers national and international doctoral students and scientists from academia and research-driven companies the opportunity to carry out a self-organized
research project at one of the 18 Helmholtz Centers.
I confirm that XXXXX from XXX has successfully applied for a
research grant to spend a research stay in XXX group at yyy. The planned
dates are 31.07.2023 to 31.10.2023. The final dates will be confirmed together with the host center and then
communicated to HIDA.

Comment: **mobile students** is covered in the first point, *Mobile researchers* in the second. So I don't think so.

Comment: Many thanks. Even the german consulate told me this but I think he does not understand my questions: You would need to apply for a national visa of the research category

Comment: I also got this from ggogle from legit website :No. You do not need to apply for a study permit in case you intend to undertake studies in the Schengen area with a stay of up to 90 days (within a 180-day period).

Comment: Is this website legit? https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/germany-researcher_en...if so it is written: A foreigner shall not be required to have a residence title for stays for research purposes not exceeding 180 days within a 360-day period, if the host research establishment in the federal territory has notified the Federal Office for Migration and Refugees that the foreigner intends to carry out part of his research activities in the federal territory..... So i hope no need

Comment: @Turan read the relevent law: [§16c - Mobility of students](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0294): *(1) By derogation from section 4 (1), a foreigner does not require a residence title for stays for study purposes not exceeding 360 days, if ...*

Comment: @ Mark Johnson  Is this website legit? immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/germany-researcher_en...if so it is written: A foreigner shall not be required to have a residence title for stays for research purposes not exceeding 180 days within a 360-day period, if the host research establishment in the federal territory has notified the Federal Office for Migration and Refugees that the foreigner intends to carry out part of his research activities in the federal territory..... So i hope no need –

Comment: @ Mark Johnson this is exactly what you mentioned and this website mentioned also A foreigner shall not be required to have a residence title for stays for research purposes not exceeding 180 days within a 360-day period, if the host research establishment in the federal territory has notified the Federal Office for Migration and Refugees that the foreigner intends to carry out part of his research activities in the federal territory, submitting the following at the same time: evidence that the foreigner possesses a valid residence title for research purposes issued by another member state.

Comment: @Turan The relevent law (§16c) make no distinction between short and long term for **students**. For both no residence permit is required. The180/360 rule applies to **researchers** (§§18e,18f).

Comment: @ Mark Johnson. My resident permit for eu is student type. But I will go to 3 months research in germany.  Though 180/360 mentioned that the host should show the german immigration: evidence that the foreigner possesses a valid residence title for research purposes issued by another member state in accordance with Directive (EU) 2016/801,.

Comment: @ Mark Johnson. evidence that the foreigner possesses a valid residence title for research purposes issued by another member state in accordance with Directive 2016/801/EU,... My resident permit in Poland is titled as student even though I am a PhD. The term "residence permit for research purposes" is vague

Comment: Does the fact that OP receives money for this research not change things? I presume a student visa would have restrictions on paid work, wouldn’t it?